# Can't dismiss keyboard for iPhone 5 and iPhone5s

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

i'm trying to dismiss the on screen keyboard programmatically and i have my code as below

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.Bottomspace.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
    })
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
    self.Bottomspace.constant = 0
}
```

It work fine for iPhone 6 and iPad, but not iPhone 5 and iPhone 5s, any suggestion?

Comment: Just when you tap outside of UITextField?

Comment: Nop, i do tap on the return key on keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 // Dismiss Keyboard when user touch screen
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 1):

Add UITextFieldDelegate to the class declaration:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

Connect the textfield or write it programmatically

```
@IBOutlet weak var userText: UITextField!
```

set your view controller as the text fields delegate in view did load:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
self.userText.delegate = self
}
```

add this delegate

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(userText: UITextField!) -> Bool {
yourtextfield.resignFirstResponder()
return true;
}
```